# jQuery submit form doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/twitts" class="dialog   " id="twitt-form" method="post" title="Dialog" selected="true">
    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
        <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="BkLNJsJfbEzfQrCTDWHW4OvvOh0l2pLPxxEJ/bGt2IY="></div>

        <input id="anonymous_id" name="anonymous[id]" type="hidden" value="22">
        <fieldset>

            <h1>Отправить сообщение</h1>
            <a class="button leftButton" type="cancel">Отмена</a>
            <a id="submit-twitt" class="button blueButton">Отправить</a>
            <!-- <input class="button blueButton" id="submit-twitt" name="commit" type="submit" value="Отправить" /> -->

            <input id="twitt-text" name="twitt[text]" size="30" type="text">

        </fieldset>
    <div class="spinner"></div>      
</form>
```

when i call

```
$('#twitt-form').submit();
```

In the debugger or inside click event handler just nothing happened. And even if set .submit handler to the form

```
    $('#twitt-form').submit(function() {
        $('#twitt-text').val('');
        $('#twitt-form').attr('selected', false);
        return false;
    });
```

Handler DOES work, but form does not submit any data. Why ?

And more: when I press Enter on form field `#twitt-text` form just submit well and .submit handler works also.

Comment: @ubercooluk `return false;` is to prevent default form action

Comment: when i press Enter on form field form just submit.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#twitt-form').submit(function() {
        $('#twitt-text').val(''); <---  this it will make form value  empty 
        $('#twitt-form').attr('selected', false);
        return false;             
    });
```

Comment: Yes it makes, and this is what i want, if i press Enter key on form field form just submit.

Comment: @s9gf4ult you are not doing anything before that so its makes no sense to dot this...or if it does than please let me know

Answer (score 0):

why you are using return false without any condition.

```
return false;
```

is to prevent default form action. that is why form is not being submitted.

Comment: And more: when i press Enter on form field #twitt-text form just submit well and .submit handler works also.

Comment: I would handle submit handler myself, but form just submits when i press Enter and i can not stop this.

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems I see with this code and two of them have been brought up now:

1. Inside your submit function, the first line will clear the input text field, so even if it submits, it won't submit anything.
2. The second thing is that `#twitt-form` is the form itself, so it doesn't have a `selected` attribute.
3. The form submit will be cancelled by the use of `return false;`.

Now if you were trying to prevent the page from going anywhere by submitting the form by AJAX, this is an example of what you can do:

```
$('#twitt-form').submit(function(e) {

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        success: function(dataFromTheServer) {
            // do whatever
        }
    });

    $('#twitt-text').val('');

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

But other than that I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I just tried exactly like this, but when i perss Enter on text field form submits twice. This is very odd for me.

Comment: It submits in ajax and as form submit, but ```return false``` must prevent event propogation.

Comment: @s9gf4ult It shouldn't submit twice as we are preventing the form submit action by using `return false;`. Are you sure you are not calling another form submission function anywhere else? In Firebug/Chrome's debugger/IE Developer Tools do you see two POST requests on the Network tab?

Comment: @s9gf4ult Upon doing additional research I added the `preventDefault()` function, but I don't think it should have mattered.

Comment: In chrome debuger on Network section i see it is two queries sends. I did'n set another ```.submit()``` handlers.

Comment: I can't read the language that the content is written in, but it seems like you don't have a submit button in the form as it is commented out in the code. But there is a `<a>` there which looks like a submit button if I'm not mistaken. Perhaps you should try using a normal `<button type='submit'>`.